# Template-based PDF renderer for flutter web

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-web

I am writing a Flutter web application that needs to have a customizable template for printing reports: inside the template there will be some placeholders that must be replaced with data at the moment of printing. The "printing" itself will be done by having the user download and open a PDF file, then print it through the browser, the OS or anything else, but that's beyond the scope, at the moment.

The default template would be something like this, where `<BUYER_DATA>` and `<TRANSACTION_DATA>` will be replaced with the data of the transaction the user is printing, along with some other "technical" tags (i.e., the page number and the pages count):

---

**Header with site name**
727 Chester Rd New Trafford, Stretford
Manchester

<BUYER_DATA>
01-12-2022 14:40

<TRANSACTION_DATA>

AppName - TM 2022
Page <PAGE_NO> of <PAGES_COUNT>

---

The user is allowed to edit this template in any aspect (boldness, size, colors, etc), provided that the tags related to the data are not removed from it.

So, to achieve this, I added a WYSIWYG html editor inside a page in order to save the template as an HTML-formatted string. And this works fine: only then I realized that [the well-known flutter printing library](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) doesn't support conversion from HTML directly to PDF on web, and all my plans began to crumble.

I then tried to discover if there's some other way to achieve the same by replacing the HTML template with something else, like markdown, but it seems that there's nothing that could help me.

**The question is: anybody knows of a package capable of converting from HTML, markdown or such, directly into PDF?**
I just need to know so I can stop googling around and decide to write my own parser for the HTML and convert it into a series of Widgets of the before-mentioned `printing` package.

Comment: For the record, at the time of writing, I did write my own simple parser for the HTML input that converts the tags into `printing` widgets. It doesn't convert the full list of HTML tags, but only a very precise subset of them and only if they are in a specific order.